# Elementor Form: How to change border color on error

Tags: php, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming, elementor

I am trying to change the border of the form when the field is not filled.
I want to change the border color of the form filed when you click "continue" without filling the form.

it currently tells you "please fill in this field" only

I have tried:

```
.elementor-1983 .elementor-element.elementor-element-9cc556a .elementor-field-group:not(.elementor-field-type-upload) .elementor-field:not(.elementor-select-wrapper):invalid{
border-color: #55ce94;
```

but this makes it always red (#55ce94) since the form is set to "required", making it red by default

Comment: can you show us what you already tried?

Comment: I hope the screenshot is fine and pointing towards the right element.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35770547/how-to-change-focus-color-when-input-is-filled-in-with-required-attribute-javasc

Comment: @m4n0 Thanks, that's the best solution I  can get